Issue generating DEM with Natural Neighbour in QGIS 3.6 on different computers
I am trying to create a DEM using the Natural Neighbour algorithm in QGIS 3.6 Noosa. On my personal computer, I can successfully generate the DEM despite encountering a warning (shown in the attached figure).

However, when I try to run the same process on another computer with the same QGIS version, the algorithm fails to generate the raster, and I receive the red warning message depicted in the figure.
I've ensured that both systems have the same version of QGIS installed, but I am still facing this issue. The configurations and parameters used are identical, but only my personal computer can generate the DEM successfully.

Why this is happening and how I can resolve this issue on the other computer?

Please don't screen shot your error message, include the message as text in your question - that makes the error code searchable for those who follow. As for the error message please translate it into english, questions in languages other than engish get a poor reception on this site and are likely to be closed.

Try to save the DEM data as *.tif or *.img on your hard drive and see if the error persists. Sometimes, saving to a temp file can cause an error.

Try changing Settings->Processing->General->Default output raster layer extension from sdat to tif.

Why do you want to do this? As an exercise to see how a DEM is created? Then it makes sense. If you just need a DEM raster, there are better ways to get one - e.g. with the pre-installed Mapzen GLobal Terrain layer from XYZ Tiles in the Browser Panel.

Once I have a problem related to the use of non ascii character in the data/output path (DTI-Chillán). As a test try to use a folder for the input data and the resulting DEM then that does not use a non-ascii character
